# selecting an element immediately after append - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have appended a div with an id div1 and immediately, the next line aims at appending contents to this div. Its not selecting. Whats going wrong?

```
$('body').append("<div id ='backFade' style='background-color: Black; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;min-height: 768px; position: absolute; -moz-opacity: 0.7; filter: alpha(opacity=70);opacity: 0.7;'></div>");
    $('body').append("<div id='popup' style='background-color:white;display:block; border: solid 3px #A9D0F5;top: 45%;left:50%; margin-top:-75.5px; margin-left:-203px;width: 500px; height: 200px; z-index: 100; position: fixed;'></div>");
    $('#popup').append("hi");
```

"hi" not coming up :(

Comment: What happens when you remove the margin-left: -203px from the div #popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just append it directly after creation?

```
$('body').append (
    $('<div id="popup"></div>')
        .css ({
            'backgroundColor': 'white',
            'display': 'block',
            'borderr': 'solid 3px #a9d0f5',
            'top': '45%',
            'left': '50%',
            'marginTop': '-75.5px',
            'marginLeft': '-203px',
            'width': '500px',
            'height': '200px',
            'zIndex': '100',
            'position': 'fixed'
        })
        .append("hi")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Create and append div1.
var div1 = $('<div id="div1" />');
$('.some-element').append(div1);

// Append contents.
div1.append('<div id="div2" />');
// Etc.
```

**Edit:** Looking at your code, I think what you want is to use the `text` function:

```
$('#popup').text('hi');
```

**Edit:** OK, try this code snippet; does it work?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $('body').append("<div id ='backFade' style='background-color: Black; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;min-height: 768px; position: absolute; -moz-opacity: 0.7; filter: alpha(opacity=70);opacity: 0.7;'></div>");
            $('body').append("<div id='popup' style='background-color:white;display:block; border: solid 3px #A9D0F5;top: 45%;left:50%; margin-top:-75.5px; margin-left:-203px;width: 500px; height: 200px; z-index: 100; position: fixed;'></div>");
            $('#popup').append("hi");
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no yaar, what i need is append . That was just an example. Even text is not working

Comment: Well there's the obvious question of whether you've got your code inside a document ready event handler?

Comment: the function which does all these in called on onload of body

Comment: there is nothing different in this except that jQuery is accessed from google.

Comment: If that doesn't work then I'm not sure. Have you verified that JavaScript is actually being executed? Try putting some `alert('foo')` calls in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('body').append("<div id ='backFade' style='background-color: Black; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;min-height: 768px; position: absolute; -moz-opacity: 0.7; filter: alpha(opacity=70);opacity: 0.7;'></div>");
        $('body').append("<div id='popup' style='background-color:white;display:block; border: solid 3px #A9D0F5;top: 45%;left:50%; margin-top:-75.5px; margin-left:-203px;width: 500px; height: 200px; z-index: 100; position: fixed;'></div>");
        $('#popup').append("hi");    
});
```

Works fine for me. In IE I had to remove the `margin: -203px` to get the hi into view.

***Edit***

Change this from the body onload to jquery document ready function like in the sample above.